# GitHub API get branch protection data

Tags: api, github

GitHub currently offers protection data on their branches via the API as an experimental feature. I'm using the header that they specify

> Accept: application/vnd.github.loki-preview+json

It works fine when I'm using this endpoint

> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch

But when trying to use other endpoints for other data...

> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection/required_pull_request_reviews

Nothing works once I add the 'protection' part and anything after it. When I curl w/o the header, I get a message saying to use the header. When including the header, I get NOT FOUND. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that even though I was getting "NOT FOUND", it was a permissions error. I added authentication and it works fine.